Dependencies issues in docker container
I'm using a Django Based Web Application. The application is using Multiple containers which includes Redis, Postgres, ElasticSearch, Kibana and Application container. When I run "docker-compose up -d --build", all containers are started but application containers is exited, When I checked logs for this container I found this
"
presshook-web-app-1  | honcho start & python manage.py qcluster
presshook-web-app-1  | /bin/sh: 1: honcho: not found
presshook-web-app-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
presshook-web-app-1  |   File "/app/manage.py", line 49, in 
presshook-web-app-1  |     from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
presshook-web-app-1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
presshook-web-app-1  | make: *** [Makefile:31: run] Error 1
" I checked my requirement.in fike and it contains all the dependencies. I tried to again install them by mentioning into dockerfile. but when i run command, I still found the same error.
I tried to add these packages in dockerfile manually in spite of they're also being used in requirement.in file. But I found the same issues on repeating again and again.

I think some more info is needed to really know why. It's probably an issue in the Dockerfile if you can post some of that.
Is it possible you're using a multi-stage Container and not copying the installed libraries? Otherwise might be worth checking if the container you're using has multiple pythons (eg a venv + a main install) and it's installing to the wrong one, or Django is loading the wrong one?
